# drag drop in android error - missing metrics?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

Im building for android 3.1 a dragable icon.. but its not dragging and my log cat keeps saying

02-29 16:23:37.020: E/View(27355): Asked for drag thumb metrics but no view
02-29 16:23:37.030: E/View(27355): Asked to draw drag shadow but no view

my code:

```
package com.s.dragDrop;

import com.s.dragDrop.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder;
import android.view.View.OnLongClickListener;

public class DragDropTestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.grid);
        View icon = findViewById(R.id.droid);
        icon.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener(){
               @Override
               public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("foo","bar");
                DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new DragShadowBuilder();
                v.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
                return true;
               }
        });
    }
}
```

can someone explain why? and what i need to do?

Answer (score 7):

To avoid getting this error, you should use the DragShadowBuilder constructor with the view your are dragging, e.g.:
"DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new DragShadowBuilder(icon);"
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.DragShadowBuilder.html